# Row that is as high as the highest child and allows the other children to CrossAxisAlignment.stretch

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a `Row` in Flutter that has a maximum height of its highest child. The other smaller children should then stretch in the available space.

I have tried using `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` and `MainAxisSize.min` on the `Row`:

```
    Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(child: Text("1")),
        Container(child: SizedBox(height: 200))
      ]);
```

In this case the `Container` with the `Text` should stretch until it is as high as the `Container` with the `SizedBox`.

However this leads to a runtime exception:

```
flutter: The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
flutter:   RenderFlex#93aae relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   creator: Row ← Column ← Column ← Padding ← Expanded ← Row ← Builder ← MediaQuery ←
flutter:   LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← ⋯
flutter:   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=174.3, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
flutter:   size: MISSING
flutter:   direction: horizontal
flutter:   mainAxisAlignment: spaceBetween
flutter:   mainAxisSize: min
flutter:   crossAxisAlignment: stretch
flutter:   textDirection: ltr
flutter:   verticalDirection: down
flutter: This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
flutter:   RenderDecoratedBox#2c670 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:     RenderPadding#94471 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:       RenderPositionedBox#38d50 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:         RenderFlex#c2d46 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:           RenderPadding#e6dc8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:           RenderParagraph#d7b38 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   RenderConstrainedBox#a7e45 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   RenderDecoratedBox#31487 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:     RenderPadding#0cf57 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:       RenderPositionedBox#df396 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:         RenderParagraph#868d2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
```

If I´m right then this exception is telling me that the `Row` is trying expand to infinity because it is not constrained.
I don´t get an exception when wrapping the `Row` in a `SizedBox(height: x)` widget, however that´s not what I want to achive.

**Is there some widget or trick that could help me to solve my problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a row that displays a red and yellow container of unknown and different size:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    red,
    yellow,
  ],
),
```

[image]

To achieve the desired result, you need two things:

- `CrossAxisAlignment.strectch`. This asks all children to take the same height – and make the row vertically fill its parent
- Wrap the `Row` into an `IntrinsicHeight` widget. This widget forces its child to take the least amount of height possible.

The end result is:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      red,
      yellow,
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]